# Display message with PHP/CSS under text form and above submit button

Tags: php, css

I would like to display a message in a page in case of user summited specific value.

The form:

- text form
- lots of free space for the message
- submit button

PHP:

```
<?php
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="t1.css">';
  echo '<div class="csstest">';
  echo '  <form action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="post">';
  echo '    <input type="text" name="data1" autocomplete="off">';
//this is the form where I want to display error message

  echo '    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="buttontest">';
  echo "  </form>";
  if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
      if ($_POST['data1']==1) {
echo '<p id="errormessage">error message</p>';
}


 }
echo "</div>';
?>
```

CSS:

```
body {


  font-family: Arial;

}

.csstest {
  padding: 40px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-color: #dddddd;

}

.csstest input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 350px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.csstest input[type=text] {
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}

.csstestinput.errormessage {
     font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
    left: 200px;
    top: 250px;
}
```

How can i display message between the text form and submit button if the user submit a specificed value ?

I am looking like something when you specifiy non standard username at gmail.com, after submit it display error message at the same css div, between the text form and the submit button.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Look at this very carefully `if ($_POST['data1']=1)` - what's "missing"? ;-)

Comment: Then nothing inside `if (isset($_POST['buttontest'])) {...}` will ever fire up.

Comment: Fred -ii-: thanks for the feedback, I will use htmlspecialchars to filter the input, this is just a basic code. Also added ==

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for submit (name it), and  `if ($_POST['data1']=1)` => `if ($_POST['data1']==1)` - Edit: ah, you changed it. Your submit won't happen. wrong name attribute and error reporting would have told you about it.

Comment: I don't understand why u have a echo of a <link> before a <div> ...

Comment: and I don't understand why the "edits as we go".

Comment: and this `<p id="errormessage">` you're referencing an id, where you have a class by the same name. That should read as `<p class="errormessage">`

Comment: Fred -ii-: thanks for the help!

Comment: you're welcome, but I honestly don't know where to throw myself here lol! I debugged your entire post. In "realtime"! lol

Comment: so.... problem solved?! lol

Comment: Alexis: am I using it incorrectly ?

Comment: Fred -ii-: yes! Thank you!

Comment: so. what would you like to do with the question then? Like I said, I debugged your code in *realtime* here ;-) so... was it just the changing of the id to a class *"in the end?"* me post an answer? seeing I did all the work *hahaha!!!*

Comment: Fred -ii-: Yes, it was,  also == fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35632309/1 where you kept on editing from my comments.

Well, at first you were assigning here `if ($_POST['data1']=1)` rather than comparing `if ($_POST['data1']==1)` which you edited after the fact.

Then, you were using the wrong name attribute for the submit button, so nothing inside that conditional statement `if (isset($_POST['buttontest'])) {...}` would have fired up as per
`<input type="submit" name="button2" value="buttontest">` being the originally named button and [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have thrown you something about it, being an undefined index buttontest notice.

Then you're referencing an id rather than a class for `<p id="errormessage">`.

As per the `.csstestinput.errormessage` CSS rule.

Which should read as `<p class="errormessage">`.

However, if you want to keep it as an id, then you will need to modify your CSS rule to read as `#errormessage` but that's your decision entirely.

Answer (score 1):

1) Double Quotes missing from last echo. 
Change: `echo "</div>';` 
To: `echo "</div>";`

2) Button too far from top, no where near text input.
Change: 
`.csstest input[type=submit] {top: 350px;}`
To:
`.csstest input[type=submit]{top: 100px;}`

3) Stylesheet references a class that does not exist. Change: `.csstestinput` To: `.csstest`

4) Stylesheet references a class that does not exist. Change: `.errormessage` To:`#errormessage`.

Personally I would place errormessage paragraph tag exactly where I wanted it and then use javascript in the IF statement to change visibility as needed. Rather then mess with relative positioning in CSS...I've found that technique useful for when I may wish user to stay on the page, but want to remove/change the error message due to a different text input. This is what I would change:
In php file:

```
//this is the form where I want to display error message
```

and:

```
if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
      if ($_POST['data1']==1) {
        echo '<p id="errormessage">error message</p>';
      }
    }
```

To:

```
echo '<p id="errormessage">error message</p>';
```

and:

```
if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
        if ($_POST['data1']==1) {
          echo '<script>document.getElementById("errormessage").style.visibility="visible";</script>';
        }
     }
```

In css file:

```
    .csstestinput.errormessage {
        font-size: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        left: 200px;
        top: 250px;
}
```

To:

```
.csstest #errormessage{
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Not sure if this is too much info, but trying to help.